# NGINX Multiple Applications on One Domain

Tags: nginx

i have 2 application on same server different ports [8080,8090] with same domain.

I have configure nginx as the following :

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name  XXX.XXX.XXX;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /{

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

        location /admin {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        }

    }
```

Problem is first application on port 8080 working fine , but other application CSS not loaded am getting 404 error . seems its point to / directory .what is the best approach to handle such case  ?

If any hit to /admin application , application should return /Login page i was looking to the nginx logs :

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [03/Sep/2016:09:00:35 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0" "-"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [03/Sep/2016:09:00:36 +0000] "GET /Login HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0" "-"
```

It shows that nginx proxy /admin to the correct application then /Login which is not on the configuration so it return 404 , if i change the configuration to the following :

```
location /admin {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/Login;
```

Its working , but CSS not , again coz all the css file URL not on the nginx configuration !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should serve your static files in another way and bypass sending requests to static files to your backends.

Add the next section before `location /{...}`

```
# serve static files
location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
  root    /usr/share/nginx/html/<folder with your static files>;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  expires 30d;
}
```

See info examples for other settings here https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#

Comment: Thanks for answer , i have update the question have a look , i believe issue related to configuration regarding redirection not serve static file ..

Comment: @moata_u How about just simply use condition 'location ~ ^/(admin|Login)/' ?